# How to share/reuse layers/variables across different graphs in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

I am building some complicated neural network model where 2 networks share some layers. My implementation was to create 2 tensorflow graphs and share layers/variables in between. However, bugs was found, just in the process of creating the network.

```
import tensorflow as tf
def create_network(self):
    self.state_tensor = tf.placeholder(tf.float64, [None, self.state_size], name="state")
    self.action_tensor = tf.placeholder(tf.float64, [None, self.action_size], name="action")
    self.actor_graph = tf.Graph()
    with self.actor_graph.as_default():
        print tf.get_variable_scope()
        state_h1 = tf.layers.dense(inputs=self.state_tensor, units=64, activation=tf.nn.relu, name="state_h1",
                                   reuse=True)
        state_h2 = tf.layers.dense(inputs=state_h1, units=32, activation=tf.nn.relu, name="state_h2", reuse=True)
        self.policy_tensor = tf.layers.dense(inputs=state_h2, units=self.action_size, activation=tf.nn.softmax,
                                             name="policy")

    self.critic_graph = tf.Graph()
    with self.critic_graph.as_default():
        print tf.get_variable_scope()
        state_h1 = tf.layers.dense(inputs=self.state_tensor, units=64, activation=tf.nn.relu, name="state_h1",
                                   reuse=True)
        state_h2 = tf.layers.dense(inputs=state_h1, units=32, activation=tf.nn.relu, name="state_h2", reuse=True)
        action_h1 = tf.layers.dense(inputs=self.action_tensor, units=64, activation=tf.nn.relu, name="action_h1")
        action_h2 = tf.layers.dense(inputs=action_h1, units=32, activation=tf.nn.relu, name="action_h2")
        fc = tf.layers.dense(inputs=[state_h2, action_h2], units=32, activation=tf.nn.relu,
                             name="fully_connected")
        self.value_tensor = tf.layers.dense(inputs=fc, units=1, activation=None, name="value")
```

The Error Message is here:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
<tensorflow.python.ops.variable_scope.VariableScope object at 0x1101c3790>
  File "/Users/niyan/code/routerRL/test.py", line 16, in <module>
    model = DPGModel(state_dim, action_dim)
  File "/Users/niyan/code/routerRL/DPGModel.py", line 10, in __init__
    self.create_network()
  File "/Users/niyan/code/routerRL/DPGModel.py", line 37, in create_network
    reuse=True)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/layers/core.py", line 216, in dense
    return layer.apply(inputs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/layers/base.py", line 303, in apply
    return self.__call__(inputs, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/layers/base.py", line 269, in __call__
    self.build(input_shapes[0])
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/layers/core.py", line 123, in build
    trainable=True)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 988, in get_variable
    custom_getter=custom_getter)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 890, in get_variable
    custom_getter=custom_getter)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 341, in get_variable
    validate_shape=validate_shape)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/layers/base.py", line 258, in variable_getter
    variable_getter=functools.partial(getter, **kwargs))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/layers/base.py", line 208, in _add_variable
    trainable=trainable and self.trainable)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 333, in _true_getter
    caching_device=caching_device, validate_shape=validate_shape)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 657, in _get_single_variable
    "VarScope?" % name)
ValueError: Variable state_h1/kernel does not exist, or was not created with tf.get_variable(). Did you mean to set reuse=None in VarScope?
```

So it seems that you can't reuse a tensorflow from other graphs. However they are indeed 2 networks and better be treated as separate graphs. Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you solved the problem? I also encountered the same needs, could you please share your solution?

Answer (score 0):

A straightforward way to do what you're asking is to initialize the weights variables with placeholders. You can share the weights between graphs by feeding the weights to the placeholders. The following example seems to work:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

weights_ph = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [10])
weights = tf.Variable(weights_ph)
loss = -tf.reduce_sum(weights)
train_op = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.001).minimize(loss)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    pyweights = np.random.normal(size=[10])
    tf.global_variables_initializer().run(feed_dict={weights_ph: pyweights})

    while True:
        pyloss, pyweights = sess.run([loss, weights, train_op], feed_dict={weights_ph: pyweights})[:2]
        print(pyloss)
```

Note that you have to feed the initial weights during tf.global_variable_initializer().run() or else it will complain and produce an error.